# How to use RTMPDump library in an OSX XCode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, static-libraries, rtmp

I have been trying to add RTMPDump (librtmp) to an Xcode project for an OS X application.

I have successfully used it for an IOS application by using librtmp-ios on cocoa pods, but am struggling to build it within my OS X project.

I keep getting errors such as `not built for the x86_64 architecture`.

Has anyone managed to get RTMPDump working in an OS X XCode project?

I have installed RTMPDump using the terminal `brew install rtmpdump` and can use the RTMP terminal program, however, cannot get it to link with my project.

Here is a link to the RTMPDump github page :

https://github.com/eugenehp/rtmpdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it working and the way to get it working I would swear by my life that I tried but here it is.

I reinstalled the RTMPDump through

```
brew install rtmpdump
```

`/usr/local/Cellar/rtmpdump/2.4+20151223/lib`
and I dragged the librtmp.dylib into my Xcode project with the add to target selected and copy selected.

Next I added the  `/usr/local/Cellar/rtmpdump/2.4+20151223/include`
 folder to my project but I did not add it to the target.

In my build setting I added `/usr/local/Cellar/rtmpdump/2.4+20151223/lib`  to my Library Search Paths

From there I was able to import my "rtmp.h" file and it was working.
I would love it if someone could explain to me why this worked and is now not giving me x86_64 errors.